# How to group data from multiple dataframe

Tags: r, grouping

I have 4 data frames.

dataframe: pickup address

```
ID    x1     x2      x3       x4         x5    x6.....x1090
1001  Place1 Place2  NA       NA         NA    NA
1002  Place1 Place2  Place 3  Place4     NA    NA
1003  Place5 Place3  Place 2  Place 2    NA    NA
1004  Place6 Place7  NA       NA         NA    NA
```

dataframe: Dropoff Address

```
ID    x1     x2      x3       x4         x5    x6.....x1090
1001  Place2 Place1  NA       NA         NA    NA
1002  Place2 Place1  Place4   Place3     NA    NA
1003  Place3 Place5  Place6   Place7     NA    NA
1004  Place7 Place6  NA       NA         NA    NA
```

dataframe: dates

```
ID    x1         x2         x3        x4         x5    x6.....x1090
1001  4/1/2020   4/1/2020   NA        NA         NA    NA
1002  4/1/2020   4/1/2020   4/3/2020  4/3/2020   NA    NA
1003  4/3/2020   4/3/2020   4/4/2020  4/5/2020   NA    NA
1004  4/5/2020   4/5/2020   NA        NA         NA    NA
```

dataframe: Time

```
    ID    x1           x2           x3            x4           x5    x6.....x1090
    1001  8:00:00 AM   4:00:00 PM   NA            NA           NA    NA
    1002  9:00:05 AM  12:35:05 PM   11:00:00 AM   4:00:00 AM   NA    NA
    1003  3:00:00 PM   6:00:00 PM   7:00:00 AM    3:00:00 PM   NA    NA
    1004  7:00:00 AM   3:00:00 PM   NA            NA           NA    NA
```

I want to group these trips by date and find the trip chain.
The output would be something like this:

```
ID    Date      Tripchain                      Time                 
1001  4/1/2020  place 1- place 2- place 1      Morning- Afternoon
1002  4/1/2020  place 1- place 2- place 1      Morning -Afternoon
1002  4/3/2020  place 3- place 4- place 3      Morning -Afternoon
1003  4/3/2020  place 5- place 3- place 5      Afternoon-Afternoon
1003  4/4/2020  place 2- place 7               Morning
1003  4/5/2020  place 2- place 7               Afternoon
1004  4/5/2020  place 6- place 7- place 6      Morning-Afternoon
```

Comment: which column is the one you are using in the 'dates' for `Date`.  Please use a small example with `dput` so that it is easier to test (instead of `..... x1090`)

Comment: @akrun I am new in r. This is a sample created similar to my dataset. I am using all the columns from x1 to x1090. For example, the 1st ID has 2 pickup locations and that ID made the trip in the same day. I want to investigate the link between the trips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think that your format of collapsing `place1-place2-...` within a string will scale horribly. If it's for reporting only (never *using* that data in that format), then fine, but otherwise I suggest you keep it separated.

The first thing to do here is convert from individual frames into a combined long format. I'll go a little further and convert the dates/times into R-native `POSIXt` objects:

```r
dat <- list(
  pivot_longer(pickup, -ID, names_to = "x", values_to = "pickup"),
  pivot_longer(dropoff, -ID, names_to = "x", values_to = "dropoff"),
  pivot_longer(dates, -ID, names_to = "x", values_to = "date"),
  pivot_longer(times, -ID, names_to = "x", values_to = "time")
) %>%
  Reduce(function(a, b) full_join(a, b, by = c("ID", "x")), .) %>%
  filter(complete.cases(.)) %>%
  mutate(
    timestamp = as.POSIXct(paste(date, time), format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S_%p"),
    date = as.Date(timestamp)
  ) %>%
  select(-x, -time)
dat
# # A tibble: 12 x 5
#       ID pickup dropoff date       timestamp              
#    <int> <chr>  <chr>   <date>     <dttm>                 
#  1  1001 Place1 Place2  2020-04-01 2020-04-01 08:00:00.000
#  2  1001 Place2 Place1  2020-04-01 2020-04-01 16:00:00.000
#  3  1002 Place1 Place2  2020-04-01 2020-04-01 09:00:05.000
#  4  1002 Place2 Place1  2020-04-01 2020-04-01 12:35:05.000
#  5  1002 Place3 Place4  2020-04-03 2020-04-03 11:00:00.000
#  6  1002 Place4 Place3  2020-04-03 2020-04-03 04:00:00.000
#  7  1003 Place5 Place3  2020-04-03 2020-04-03 15:00:00.000
#  8  1003 Place3 Place5  2020-04-04 2020-04-03 18:00:00.000
#  9  1003 Place2 Place6  2020-04-04 2020-04-04 07:00:00.000
# 10  1003 Place2 Place7  2020-04-05 2020-04-05 15:00:00.000
# 11  1004 Place6 Place7  2020-04-05 2020-04-05 07:00:00.000
# 12  1004 Place7 Place6  2020-04-05 2020-04-05 15:00:00.000
```

From here, to get to where you want to go, I think we can order them (by timestamp), group them (by id), and then combine. Oh, and convert to human-readable "time-of-day".

```r
time2human <- function(x) {
  as.character(
    cut(as.numeric(format(x, format = "%H")), c(-1, 4, 12, 17, 20, 25),
        labels = c("Night", "Morning", "Afternoon", "Evening", "Night"))
  )
}

dat %>%
  arrange(timestamp) %>%
  group_by(ID, date) %>%
  summarize(
    Tripchain = paste(c(pickup, last(dropoff)), collapse = " - "),
    Timeframe = paste(time2human(min(timestamp)), time2human(max(timestamp)),
                      sep = " - "),
    Time1 = first(timestamp), Time2 = last(timestamp)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 7 x 6
#      ID date       Tripchain                Timeframe             Time1                   Time2                  
#   <int> <date>     <chr>                    <chr>                 <dttm>                  <dttm>                 
# 1  1001 2020-04-01 Place1 - Place2 - Place1 Morning - Afternoon   2020-04-01 08:00:00.000 2020-04-01 16:00:00.000
# 2  1002 2020-04-01 Place1 - Place2 - Place1 Morning - Morning     2020-04-01 09:00:05.000 2020-04-01 12:35:05.000
# 3  1002 2020-04-03 Place4 - Place3 - Place4 Night - Morning       2020-04-03 04:00:00.000 2020-04-03 11:00:00.000
# 4  1003 2020-04-03 Place5 - Place3          Afternoon - Afternoon 2020-04-03 15:00:00.000 2020-04-03 15:00:00.000
# 5  1003 2020-04-04 Place3 - Place2 - Place6 Evening - Morning     2020-04-03 18:00:00.000 2020-04-04 07:00:00.000
# 6  1003 2020-04-05 Place2 - Place7          Afternoon - Afternoon 2020-04-05 15:00:00.000 2020-04-05 15:00:00.000
# 7  1004 2020-04-05 Place6 - Place7 - Place6 Morning - Afternoon   2020-04-05 07:00:00.000 2020-04-05 15:00:00.000
```

I kept `Time1` and `Time2` in case you still have need for full timestamps. You will need to update the `time2human` function so that the cuts are more amenable to your liking. (I have "hours" of -1 and +25 to ensure I bound all possible hours completely; I could be more precise and careful with it, but this is safe enough.)

Lastly, if you prefer to have dates and times in the formats you started with, use `format(..., format=...)` to get what you want; I prefer (and recommend) keeping them in `Date` and `POSIXt` formats as long as possible, as they are inherently numeric and therefore easily comparable/sortable. Once they convert to strings, operations like that become less clear (such as trying to sort `4/1/2019` before `3/1/2020`, for example).

Comment: Farah, does this answer your question? If so, please accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @r2evans, I tried the code and it gives me a result with NA's in the date and time column. Is there a specific date and time format that I should set in my csv file?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to paste, Farah, but I see nothing. The code works with the data as I copied and adjusted from your question. All I removed was the `x` variable (which contains `x1`, `x2`, etc, from the pivot) and `time` (which is now encapsulated in `timestamp`). If you would prefer a categorical `time` that is not numerical or easily sortable/comparable, then feel free to convert `timestamp` back into a string. `date` is still in there, so perhaps you changed a label or name in the code?